# Length of Latus Rectum for a General Parabola

Tags: conic-sections

This is an extension my earlier questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2044922/168053) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2042028/168053) on parabolas.

> Find the length of the Latus Rectum of the General Parabola
>   $$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

Comment: To help you, we need to know what your background in this question is, and what you’ve tried for solving it.

Comment: @Lubin - Thanks for reading. I've just posted an answer. Have worked this out after the two earlier questions, and another question by someone else on the LR of a parametric parabola.

Answer (score 4):

$$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0\qquad\cdots (1)$$
Put $u=Ax+Cy, v=Cx-Ay$ and solving for $x,y$ and putting $K=A^2+C^2$ gives
$$y=\frac {Cu-Av}{K}; \qquad x=\frac {Au+Cv}{K}\qquad\cdots (2)$$
From $(1),(2)$,

$$\begin{align}
u^2+D\left(\frac {Au+Cv}{K}\right)+E\left(\frac{Cu-Av}{K}\right)+F&=0\\
\left(u+\frac {AD+CE}{2K}\right)^2&=\frac{AE-CD}{K}\bigg\lbrace v+\frac{K}{AE-CD}\left[\left(\frac{AD+CE}{2K}\right)^2-F\right]\bigg\rbrace\\
\text{Dividing by }\sqrt{K}\cdot \sqrt{K} \text{ to normalize }u,v \hspace{1cm} \\
\text{and putting }M=AE-CD,\hspace{1cm}\\
{\underbrace{\left(\frac u{\sqrt{K}}+\frac {AD+CE}{2K\sqrt{K}}\right)}_U}^2&=\underbrace{\frac{M}{K\sqrt{K}}}_{4\alpha}\underbrace{\bigg\lbrace \frac v{\sqrt{K}}+\frac{K}{M\sqrt{K}}\left[\left(\frac{AD+CE}{2K}\right)^2-F\right]\bigg\rbrace}_V\\
U^2&=4\alpha V\\
\text{Length of Latus Rectum  } = |4\alpha |&=\bigg|\frac M{\;\;K^{\frac 32}}\bigg|=\color{red}{\frac {\big|AE-CD\big|}{\;\;\big(A^2+C^2\big)^{\frac 32}}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I thought the latus rectum was a chord. Are you calculating its length?

Comment: @Lubin - Yes, that's right. Edited accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Something’s off. Set $A=\sqrt a$, $E=-1$ and the other coefficients to $0$ for the equation $y=ax^2$. Your formula produces $\sqrt a/a$, but the correct result is $1/a$. Compared to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041463/265466), your result is missing a factor of $\sqrt{A^2+C^2}$ in the denominator.

Comment: Hmmm how could this arise? The method substituting $u,v$ is effectively rotating the parabola, and completing the square etc is effectively translating it to the origin, and the steps seem quite procedural. Why does it give a different answer?

Comment: @amd - OK, sorted out.