# Equation of parabola passes through $4$ distinct points

Tags: conic-sections

> Equation of axis of parabola which

> passes through the point $(0,1)\ , \ (0,2)$

> And $(2,0)\ ,\ (2,2)$ is

Let general equation of conic is

$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0\cdots (1)$

And it represent parabola if $h^2=ab$

Parabola passes through $(0,1)$

Then put into $(1)$

$b+2f+c=0\cdots(2)$

Also parabola passes through $(0,2)$

Then $4b+4f+c=0\cdots (3)$

Also parabola passes through $(2,0)$

Then $4a+4g+c=0\cdots (4)$

Also parabola passes through $(2,2)$

Then $4a+8h+4b+4g+4f+c\cdots (5)$

$(4a+4g+c)+(4b+4f+c)+8h-c=0$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get $\displaystyle h=\frac {c}{8}$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$

$\displaystyle b+2f=4b+4f\Longrightarrow 2f=-3b $

Put into $(2)$ and $(3)$

$\displaystyle b=\frac{c}{2}$ and $\displaystyle f=-\frac{3c}{4}$

And $\displaystyle h^2=ab\Longrightarrow \frac{c^2}{64}=\frac{ac}{2}\Longrightarrow a=\frac{c}{32}$

Put all into $(4)$

$\displaystyle \frac{4c}{32}+4g+c=0\Longrightarrow g=-\frac{9c}{32}$

Put all values into $(1)$

$\displaystyle \frac{c}{32}x^2+\frac{c}{4}xy+\frac{c}{2}y^2-\frac{9}{16}x-\frac{3c}{2}y+c=0$

$x^2+8xy+16y^2-18x-48y+32=0$

Buti did not know how I find axis of parabola

Please have a look

Comment: A geometric hint is to notice that the chord through the first pair of points is parallel to the chord through the second pair (as they're both vertical). It's "known" that the midpoints of parallel chords lie on a line parallel to the parabola's axis, so you can at least get the slope. ... How you might proceed from there  depends upon the types of tools you can use. (BTW: A GeoGebra sketch seems to confirm that your final equation is correct ... but you left out a $c$ in the next-to-last version of it.)

Comment: take a look https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=contour+plot+x%5E2%2B8xy%2B16y%5E2-18x-48y%2B32%3D0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to show a solution which uses the following claim, and then add a proof of the claim and an important fact which might interest you.

**Claim** : The equation of a parabola can be written as
$$\bigg(f(x,y)\bigg)^2+g(x,y)=0$$
where
$f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the axis of symmetry, and $g(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the tangent at vertex. (Note that the axis of symmetry is perpendicular to the tangent at vertex.)

---

**Solution** :

You correctly got
$$x^2+8xy+16y^2-18x-48y+32=0$$
which can be written as
$$(x+4y+c)^2+(-2c-18)x+(-8c-48)y-c^2+32=0$$

Since we want to find $c$ such that the line $x+4y+c=0$ is perpendicular to the line $(-2c-18)x+(-8c-48)y-c^2+32=0$, solving
$$1\times (-2c-18)+4\times (-8c-48)=0$$
gives $c=-\dfrac{105}{17}$, and so the equation of the axis of symmetry is $x+4y-\dfrac{105}{17}=0$.

---

In the following, I'll add a proof of the claim.

**Claim** : The equation of a parabola can be written as
$$\bigg(f(x,y)\bigg)^2+g(x,y)=0$$
where
$f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the axis of symmetry, and $g(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the tangent at vertex.

*Proof* :

The equation
$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2fy+g=0\tag2$$
represents a parabola iff $ac=b^2$ and
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & d \\
b & c & f \\
d & f & g \\
\end{vmatrix}\not=0\tag3$$
(see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html))

Multiplying the both sides of $(2)$ by $a$, and letting $$A=a,C=b,D=2ad,E=2af,F=ag$$
we see that, in general, the equation of a parabola is given by
$$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0\tag4$$
(where $(A,C)\not=(0,0)$, and $(3)\iff CD-AE\not=0$) which can be written as
$$\bigg(f(x,y)\bigg)^2+g(x,y)=0$$
where
$$\begin{align}f(x,y)&=Ax+Cy+\frac {AD+CE}{2(A^2+C^2)}
\\\\g(x,y)&=\frac{CD-AE}{A^2+C^2}(Cx-Ay+G)
\\\\G&=\frac{4F(A^2+C^2)^2-(AD+CE)^2}{4(A^2+C^2)(CD-AE)}\end{align}$$
Note that $f(x,y)=0$ is perpendicular to $g(x,y)=0$.

Now, we can see the followings by some calculations :

- The line $g(x,y)=0$ is tangent to the parabola $(4)$ at $P\bigg(H,\dfrac{CH+G}{A}\bigg)$ where $H=\dfrac{-2CG(A^2+C^2)-A(AD+EC)}{2(A^2+C^2)^2}$.
- The line $f(x,y)=0$ intersects the parabola $(4)$ only at $P$.

From these, we can say the followings :

- $f(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the axis of symmetry
- $g(x,y)=0$ is the equation of the tangent at the vertex
- $P$ is the vertex of the parabola.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

Finally, I'll add an important fact which might interest you.

The equation of a parabola
$$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
can be written as
$$\bigg(\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{A^2+C^2}}\bigg)^2=\frac{AE-CD}{(A^2+C^2)^{\frac 32}}\cdot\frac{Cx-Ay+G}{\sqrt{A^2+C^2}}$$

where

- $\dfrac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{A^2+C^2}}$ represents the distance from $(x,y)$ to the axis of symmetry
- $\dfrac{|AE-CD|}{(A^2+C^2)^{\frac 32}}$ represents the length of its latus rectum (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2051256/78967))
- $\dfrac{|Cx-Ay+G|}{\sqrt{A^2+C^2}}$ represents the distance from $(x,y)$ to the tangent at the vertex.

Answer (score 4):

What you've done is correct.

One way to find the axis is to write the equation as $(x+4y)^2-18x-48y+32=0,$ then you know the axis is parallel to $x+4y=0.$ The tangent at vertex is orthogonal and parallel to $4x-y.$ Now you can find where $4x-y+c$ intersects doubly to find the vertex. $$x^2+8x(4x+c)+16(4x+c)^2-18x-48(4x+c)+32=0$$ or $$289x^2+(136c-210)x+16c^2-48c+32=0$$ and this has discriminant $$(136c-210)^2-4\cdot 289\cdot (16c^2-4c+32)=(-4)(408c - 1777)$$ so the discriminant is zero for $c=\frac{1777}{408}.$ The vertex is the intersection of the tangent at vertex and the parabola. So solve $$x^2+8x(4x+\frac{1777}{408})+16(4x+\frac{1777}{408})^2-18x-48(4x+\frac{1777}{408})+32=0$$ or $$(1734x+1147)^2\frac1{10404}$$ and put back into the tangent at vertex to find $y.$
The vertex then is $(-\frac{1147}{1734},\frac{11857}{6936}).$
The axis goes through the vertex  so the axis is $${ x+4y=\frac{105}{17}}.$$ As a bonus the tangent at vertex form is then $$(x+4y-105/17)^2=(96/(4\cdot 17))(4x-y+1777/408).$$ For fun I've also found the focus/directrix form $$17\cdot ((x+\frac{59}{102})^2+(y-\frac{689}{408})^2-(4x-y+\frac{113}{24})^2/17)=0$$

[image: The parabola with axis/tangent at vertex and focus/directrix]

Comment: Thanku Jan magnous . I have understand axis is parallel to $x+4y=0$ and tangent is perpendicular to axis. i .e $4x-y+c=0$ and after that I am not getting how you find vertex and parabola equation in standard form. Can you explain me in detail.

Comment: @PritiBisht You solve the system of your equation and $4x-y+c=0$ resulting in a quadratic ($c$ is a parameter), then you take the discriminant to get an equation for $c$ alone.

Comment: Thanks John Magnous

Answer (score 0):

General equation is

$ A x^2 + B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0 $

Plug in the points, you get the following four equations

$ C + E + F = 0 $

$ 4 C + 2 E + F = 0 $

$ 4 A + 2 D + F = 0 $

$ 4A + 4 B + 4 C + 2 D + 2 E + F = 0 $

This is a linear system of $4$ equations in $6$ unknowns.  I fed this system of equations to a solver that I developed myself, and it gave me the following solution

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = t (-0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) + s (-0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0, -1.5, 1 ) $

Setting $t = 2 \alpha$ and $ s = 4 \beta $, the solution can be written as

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = \alpha (-1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0) + \beta (-1, 1, 2, 0, -3, 1) $

A necessary condition on these parameters to have a parabola is that $B^2 - 4 A C = 0$.  If $\alpha = 0 $, then $B^2 - 4 A C = \beta^2 (1 + 8) = 9 \beta^2 \ne 0 $.  Therefore, we can assume that $\alpha \ne 0 $ and pull it out and divide by it, to get

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = (-1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0) + \lambda (-1, 1, 2, 0, -3, 1) $

where $\lambda = \beta / \alpha $

Now the parabola condition becomes,

$ \lambda^2 - 4 (-1 - \lambda)(2 \lambda) = 0 $

Which give two values for $\lambda$, namely $\lambda = 0 $ and $\lambda = - 8/ 9 $

If $\lambda = 0 $ , then we have

$ - x^2 + 2 x = 0 $

which is not a parabola, but a pair of parallel lines.  With the other solution

$ - \dfrac{1}{9} x^2 - \dfrac{8}{9} xy - \dfrac{16}{9} y^2 + 2 x + \dfrac{8}{3} y - \dfrac{8}{9} = 0 $

Mutliplying through by $(-9)$

$  x^2 + 8 x y + 16 y^2 - 18 x - 24 y + 8 = 0 $

is the only possible parabola.