# Determinant-of-Determinants Form equivalent of $\mathbf{ x^T Q x}$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

From the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055097/168053) and [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055113/168053) posted, we see that
$$\begin{matrix}
\big((x-c)&(y-r)&1\big)\\\\\\\\\\\end{matrix}\;\;
\left(\begin{matrix}
p^2
 &-ap
  &\;\;\scriptsize\frac q2\left|\begin{matrix} a &b\\p&q\end{matrix}\right|\\
-ap
 &a^2
    &\scriptsize-\frac b2\left|\begin{matrix}a&b\\p&q\end{matrix}\right|\\
\scriptsize\frac q2\left|\begin{matrix}a&b\\p&q\end{matrix}\right|
 &\scriptsize-\frac b2 \left|\begin{matrix} a&b\\p&q\end{matrix}\right|
  &\;\;\;0
\end{matrix}\right)\;\;
\left(\begin{matrix}x-c\\\\y-r\\\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

is equivalent to

$$\hspace{2cm}\left|\;\;\begin{matrix}
\left|\;\;\;\begin{matrix}
-a&&-p\\
-b&&-q
\end{matrix}\;\;\;\right|
&&\left|\begin{matrix}
-a&-p\\
(x-c)&(y-r)\end{matrix}\right|
\\\\
\left|\begin{matrix}
-a&-p\\
(x-c)&(y-r)\end{matrix}\right|
&&\left|\begin{matrix}
-b&-q\\
(x-c)&(y-r)\end{matrix}\right|
\end{matrix}\;\;\right|$$

> **Question**:
>   Is it always possible to express the quadratic form $\mathbf {x^T Q x}$, where $\mathbf Q$ is symmetric, in the form of a determinant of determinants, i.e.
>   $$\left|\begin{matrix}|\mathbf A|&|\mathbf B|\\|\mathbf B|&|\mathbf C|\end{matrix}\right|$$
>   ? If so, express $\mathbf {A, B, C}$ in terms of $\mathbf {x, Q}$.