# Parametric equation of a circle - Proof

Tags: circles, education

I know that a circle can be described with infinite parametric equations. Given a parametric equation $(x(t), y(t))$, how can I prove that the curve is a circle?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you could just convert to cartesian, where it will be obvious.

Comment: You need some information about the parametric equation to prove that is describes a circle (or even part of a circle).  A typical approach would be to find a center $(h,k)$ and prove that $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2$ is a positive constant (radius squared) as time $t$ varies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to show that for all $t$, $x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ is the same positive real number.  You would also have to show that for an appropriate parameter interval, the entire circle is generated.

Comment: Hi @paw88789. For example, how can I prove that, when t chenges, $\left(\left(cos(t)\right),\left(sin(t)\right)\right)$ describes the whole circle and not only a part?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi For instance if $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, then you will start and end at $(1,0)$, corresponding to one full traversal of the circle.  (By checking the values of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ at the ends of the parameter interval.)

Answer (score 3):

This answer shows what to do if we don't know that the circle is centred at zero. A curve is part of a circle if and only if its radius of curvature is a finite constant (and hence so is its curvature):

A circle satisfies $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$. Differentiating,
$$ (x-a)x' + (y-b)y' = 0, $$
or
$$ \frac{x-a}{y-b} = -\frac{y'}{x'} \implies \frac{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}{\lvert x' \rvert} = \frac{\sqrt{(y-b)^2+(x-a)^2}}{\lvert y-b \rvert} = \frac{c}{\lvert y-b \rvert}, $$
(squaring both sides, adding $1$ and taking a square root) and differentiating the first of these again,
$$ \frac{-y''x'+x''y'}{x'^2} = \frac{x'}{y-b} -\frac{(x-a)y'}{(y-b)^2} = \frac{1}{y-b} \left( x' + \frac{y'^2}{x'} \right) = \frac{x'^2+y'^2}{(y-b)x'}, $$
so
$$ \left| \frac{x''y'-y''x'}{x'^2+y'^2} \right| = \frac{\lvert x' \rvert}{\lvert y-b \rvert} = \frac{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}{c}. $$
Thus 
$$ \left| \frac{x''y'-y''x'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}} \right| = \frac{1}{c}. $$
It therefore is sensible to call the reciprocal of this quantity the radius of curvature.

Now, let's show the other direction: that if $\left| \frac{x''y'-y''x'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}} \right|$ is constant, $(x,y)$ describes an arc of a circle. It is useful to know how the curvature changes under reparametrisation: if $t=t(s)$, and we use the convention that $' = d/dt$, $\dot{} = d/ds$, then $$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2 = \dot{t}^2(x'^2+y'^2),$$
and
$$ \ddot{x}\dot{y}-\ddot{y}\dot{x} = (x'\ddot{t}+x''\dot{t}^2)y'\dot{t} - (y'\ddot{t}+y''\dot{t}^2)x'\dot{t} = \dot{t}^3(x''y'-y''x'), $$
and so the curvature is invariant under reparametrisation, which is sensible.

It's especially nice because we can re-parametrise using the arc-length, where $x'^2+y'^2=1$, so it amounts to solving
$$ x''y'-y''x' = 1/c. $$
Differentiating the arc-length equation gives
$$ x''x'+y''y' = 0 \implies y''= -\frac{x''x'}{y'}, $$
so 
$$ \frac{1}{c} = x''y' +\frac{x''x'^2}{y'} = x''\frac{x'^2+y'^2}{y'} = \frac{x''}{y'}, $$
so $y'=cx''$ and $x'=-cy''$, a system of equations which, together with $x'^2+y'^2=1$, has only solutions of the form $x=a+c\cos{((t-t_0)/c)}$, $y=b+c\sin{((t-t_0)/c)}$, i.e. circular arcs.

Comment: Hi @Chappers. I have two questions for you. 1. Where comes from the term $\frac{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}{\lvert x' \rvert}$ at the beginning of proof? 2. What is the difference between the derivatives $x'$ and $\dot{x}$? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Square both sides of the left equation, add $1$ and take the square root. Sorry if that wasn't as obvious as I thought! 2. I meant $x'$ to mean $\frac{d}{dt} x(t)$ and $\dot{x}$ to be $\frac{d}{ds} x(t(s)) $, but I suppose it's not that clear. I'll edit.

Comment: Very nice and complete solution (+1). I am intrigued to see the appearance of the rarely-encountered $\cdot^{3/2}$ (power) which also appears in the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2051287/168053) on the length of the latus rectum of a parametric parabola. Could there be any relationship between the two?

Comment: @hypergeometric I don't think they're related: the parabola expression is effectively $(x''y'-y''x')^2/(x''^2+y''^2)^{3/2}$ (which, in particular, is constant in that case).

Comment: @hypergeometric And rotating and reparametrising the original expression into the standard form $(x_0,y_0)+(\alpha t^2,2\alpha t)$ gives $\alpha=(aB-Ab)^2/(a^2+A^2)^{3/2}$ anyway.

Comment: OK. Just that one doesn't often come across $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard definition of a circle:

> you have to prove that there exists a point $C$ that has the same distance from any pointwit the coordinates $(x(t),y(t))$