# Parametric equation appears to generate circle and violate $x(t)^2+y(t)^2={R+}$

Tags: solution-verification, circles, parametric

The context of the equations is from plotting the real against the imaginary impedance of an RC circuit however the problem is entirely mathematical.

Given the two equations:

$x(w) = \frac{R}{C^2 R^2 w^2 + 1}$

$y(w) = \frac{C R^2 w}{C^2 R^2 w^2 + 1}$

Where R, C and w are positive reals.

Plotting these equations appears to yeild a arc which follows a circle. Arc shown in green, see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m4yffxmpn6 for interactive version.

Purple - A circle centered at x=R and r=R

Red/Blue are functions x and y

[image: A circle]

Following the suggestion of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2334966/372157) question I tried to prove this by squaring each component and summing them and seeing if the result is constant.

$x(w)^2 + y(w)^2$
$=\frac{R^2}{((RCw)^2+1)^2} + \frac{R^4 C^2 w^2}{((RCw)^2 + 1)^2}$
$=\frac{R^2}{((RCw)^2 + 1}$

This is still a function of $w$ and so not constant for all $w$ and the curve is not a circluar arc.

Can this be right? It looks so much like a circular arc that I am second guessing myself at this proof being right.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is for a circle centered at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the hint, thought its not entirely clear to me how this helps. let k be some constant and we still get a function of w $(x(w)-k)^2+y(w)^2=k^2 - \frac{2Rk-R^2}{C^2R^2w^2 + 1}$

Setting $k=R$ simplifies things a bit but we still have that w? How does it help if the circle is not centered (0,0)?

Comment: The hint was supposed to show you that the origin can't be the center. Actually, without further investigation, you know nothing about the center or the radius. Well, it's not difficult to see the ordinate of the center must be $0$, as $y$ is odd. And by studying the variations of $x$ you would find at once that the abscissa of the center has to be $R/2$, and the radius $R/2$ as well. Below is an algebraic derivation without prior assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your parametric equation describes (at least part of) a circle, with unknown center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$. Hence, for all $w$,

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2=0$$

The first term is

$$\left(\frac{R}{R^2C^2w^2+1}-a\right)^2=\frac{(R-aR^2C^2w^2-a)^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}=\frac{a^2R^4C^4w^4+(R-a)^2-2a(R-a)R^2C^2w^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}$$

Then

$$\left(\frac{R^2Cw}{R^2C^2w^2+1}-b\right)^2=\frac{(R^2Cw-bR^2C^2w^2-b)^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}\\=\frac{b^2R^4C^4w^4+R^4C^2w^2+b^2-2bR^4C^3w^3-2bR^2Cw+2b^2R^2C^2w^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}$$

And the last is

$$\frac{-r^2(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}=\frac{-r^2R^4C^4w^4-r^2-2r^2R^2C^2w^2}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}$$

Now, add the terms. Since we managed to get the same denominator, factor it out. When doing the addition, keep $w^k$ terms together.

The equation at the beginning becomes :

$$\frac{1}{(R^2C^2w^2+1)^2}\left[(a^2+b^2-r^2)R^4C^4w^4-2bR^4C^3w^3+(R^4C^2+2b^2R^2C^2-2a(R-a)R^2C^2-2r^2R^2C^2)w^2-2bR^2Cw+(R-a)^2+b^2-r^2\right]=0$$

This has to be true for all $w$, hence the right factor is a polynomial in $w$ with null coefficients.

Therefore:

- $a^2+b^2=r^2$
- $b=0$
- $R^2C^2(R^2+2b^2-2a(R-a)-2r^2)=0$ hence $R^2+2b^2-2a(R-a)-2r^2=0$
- $(R-a)^2+b^2-r^2=0$, hence $R^2+a^2+b^2-r^2-2aR=0$

From the first and last we get $R(R-2a)=0$ hence $a=R/2$. Put this and $b=0$ in the first and we get $r=R/2$. We can check with the third:

$$R^2+2b^2-2a(R-a)-2r^2=R^2-\frac{1}{2}R^2-\frac{1}{2}R^2=0$$

So the parametric curve is indeed an arc of the circle of center $(R/2,0)$ and radius $R/2$.

Is it the full circle? No, the circle passes through the origin, but $x$ can't be zero.

Are all other points on the circle reached? Let's see. $y$ is an odd function of $w$, so the curve is symmetric wrt the $x$ axis. For $w\to\infty$, $x\to0$, and for $w=0$, $x=R$. Therefore, all abscissas of points on the circle are reached except $0$. That is, the parametric curve, defined for $w\in\Bbb R$, is exactly the aforementioned circle minus one point at the origin. For $w>0$ you keep only points of the circle such that $y>0$ (upper half circle).